# Export Crashlytics(not Firebase) data to Excel

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, crashlytics

Is there any way to export the data of list of the crashes in Crashlytics to Excel (or any spreadsheet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Firebase Crashlytics then You can export your Crashlytics data into [BigQuery](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery/) for further analysis. BigQuery allows you to analyze the data using BigQuery SQL, export it to another cloud provider, and use it for visualization and custom dashboards with Google Data Studio.

Here are is the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export#working_with_firebase_crashlytics_data_in_bigquery) to additional resources on this.